# Enlarge a png picture created on-the-fly in R markdown.

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R markdown to create a PDF report with images, tables, and text. One of the images is created on-the-fly by a linked user interface. In the .Rmd file, I have R code embedded to load and plot the image. I am using the 'png' package to load the image, and grid::raster() to plot the image. Depending on what the user provides the interface, the image size changes. I would like to ensure this on-the-fly png image fills an entire page in the PDF report. Is there a way I can do this?

Thank you for your time!

````
Here is my code: 
#Process Chain

```{r, echo=FALSE} 
filename<-paste("PC_",job,".png",sep="")
img<-readPNG(filename)
#H<-dim(img)[1]
#W<-dim(img)[2]
grid::grid.raster(img)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

This will scale the image to fill the entire *width* of the PDF output:

````
---
title: "PNG test"
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=0in
---

```{r out.width='8.5in', out.height='11in'}
library(png)
filename<-paste("PC_",job,".png",sep="")
img<-readPNG(filename)
grid::grid.raster(img)
```
````

I tried several things to get it to stretch the image height to fill the page as well, but to no avail.

It may be easier to perform any stretching or padding as you are generating the PNG, before passing it to knitr.